# How to get center of map for v2 android maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

In Google Maps for Android **v1**, MapView had a convenience method: 
`getMapCenter()`.  Now I cannot figure out how to get map center with **v2** of this api.  I have perused the API documentation, but there is no mention of such a feature.  Please advise.

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 202, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems you can get the center this way:

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().target
```

where mMap is the GoogleMap instance from your activity. This will return a LatLng object which basically represents the center of the map.

Note that the `GeoPoint` class is not available anymore.

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html

target is "The location that the camera is pointing at." (I tested it with the sample code and it worked okay for me)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that GeoPoint was unavailable in v2.  I was gonna use the VisibleRegion object to calculate the middle point between the four corners of the map display.

Comment: @Radu Comaneci How to do the same with html javascript? Any idea

Comment: Good answer, but this gets affected if im using a padding for example to move the copyright google sign, so the center of the map will get this padding value as well

Answer (score 35):

I have found two ways of do this:

1) The easiest, The first is using the target property in the Map's CameraPosition Object

```
 LatLng center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

2) The second is using a VisibleRegion object:

```
VisibleRegion visibleRegion = mMap.getProjection()
                    .getVisibleRegion();

Point x = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(
                    visibleRegion.farRight);

Point y = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(
                    visibleRegion.nearLeft);

Point centerPoint = new Point(x.x / 2, y.y / 2);

LatLng centerFromPoint = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(
                    centerPoint);
```

I have compared both answers:

```
Log.d("MapFragment: ", "Center From camera: Long: " + center.longitude
                        + " Lat" + center.latitude);

Log.d("Punto x", "x:" + x.x + "y:" + x.y);
Log.d("Punto y", "y:" + y.x + "y:" + y.y);

Log.d("MapFragment: ", "Center From Point: Long: "
                    + centerFromPoint.longitude + " Lat"
                    + centerFromPoint.latitude);
```

Comment: Option 2 gives a completely different answer for me than option 1. Maybe because I have a transparent Toolbar? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: so which method is accurate?

Comment: @shontauro How to do the same with html javascript? Any idea

Comment: javascript no idea.

Comment: Option 2 Gave a more accurate position. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can use :

```
latlng=map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.getCenter();
```

Comment: Get the accuracy with this solution

Answer (score 7):

to get center of map I used onMapReady() method in activity, then used `googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener() method to get position of Came`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googMap) {
    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {

       Log.i("centerLat",cameraPosition.target.latitude);

       Log.i("centerLong",cameraPosition.target.longitude);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to get the position *once* (e.g. after the user has stopped panning the map), use `setOnCameraIdleListener`:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener

```
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        LatLng position = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
        Log.d("MapActivity", "Position: " + position);
    }
});
```

or using a Java 8 lambda:

```
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(() -> {
    LatLng position = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
    Log.d("MapActivity", "Position: " + position);
});
```

Note that the listener registered with `setOnCameraChangeListener` is called many times, and as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener) states:

> This may be called as often as once every frame and should not perform expensive operations.

Answer (score 3):

best way use cameraPosition

**java:**

```
LatLng centerMap = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

**kotlin:**

```
googleMap?.cameraPosition?.target?.let {
    // it is LatLng center
}
```